# What does the word term mean when used in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

So I have a boss from Ireland that works out of the UK.  He tells me that he is on leave for a half term?  What is he talking about?

Comment: Although *school terms* are usually 10-12 weeks long, he might not mean he's on leave for 5-6 weeks (*half **of a** term*). Without more context it's impossible to know, but I'd have thought quite likely he means he's on leave for ***a/the** half-term [holiday]* (i.e. - he's off work for the same week or so that most schoolchildren have as "holiday" *between* the two halves of the term).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Term as in part of an academic year, more often called semesters in the US, though strictly that only applies to two-term systems and Irish schools tend to use trimesters, though many third-level institutions changed to semesters relatively recently.

Schools often have a break in the middle of the term, called *half-term*, of which one is coming up soon, the exact time depending on the school. This break is normally relatively short, around a week.

If you aren't in an academic field yourself, I'd guess that their children will be on a half-term break, and they are taking to be with them.

Comment: Seems like the break would be a few weeks right?

Comment: @RyeBread  Half-terms in the UK usually last one week, there's one between Christmas and Easter, one before the summer holidays, and one sometime around October or November, I can't remember which. Schools in the UK will end in mid-July for six weeks. More info here: http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/education/primary_and_post_primary_education/attendance_and_discipline_in_schools/school_terms_in_primary_and_postprimary.html

Comment: Wow - So the kids only get 3 weeks off per year? @Mari-LouA

Comment: No, they do have Christmas, Easter and the summer holidays too.

Comment: @RyeBread *Half-term* signifies *when* the break occurs, not how long it is. In the U.S., we could call it a *mid-term break*, though people almost always use more specific names, e.g. *fall break* and *spring break*. After all, for schools on the quarter system, spring break falls in between terms, not in the middle of one.

Comment: Yes, the bigger breaks are between terms, particularly over Christmas and the longest break during the summer, between the end of one academic year and the next.

Comment: And they just use the phrase half-term for any of these breaks - which are different lengths?  It is confusing.  When we say Spring Break in the US - everyone knows it is about a week, as XMas Break being 1-2 weeks, Fall break being a week or less, and Summer break being 2-3 months.   Is there any rules for half-term like this?

Comment: No, half-term is only for the shorter breaks. The year will start after the summer break, then the first half-term break will often be called the Hallowe'en break in Ireland, then at the end of that term there's a longer Winter/Christmas break, then the next half-term tends to just be called "half term", then there's a  break at Easter before the last term, which normally doesn't have a half-term, but is shorter and with two bank holidays during it, and as that term ends it's summer holiday again. Different schools will vary slightly, but half-term is almost never longer than a week.

Comment: Mari-Lou A, the British school year normally ends in late July, with the exact date depending on particular schools. Students in Year 11 will finish earlier than this, about mid-July, because they have study leave which is time to revise for GCSE exams and then, the exams themselves.

Comment: @Tristanr thanks for the clarification. I remember the school summer holidays being six weeks, and starting on the first week of September, guess it's the second week. Italian kids are luckier, they finish school sometime around 10th June and go back to school around the 2nd week of September! But they don't get any half terms, just the standard festivities.

Comment: Mari-Lou A, that's understandable. Italy has much hotter weather for longer periods, in summer, than the UK has.

Answer (score 0):

From the Cambridge English dictionary:
in the UK, a short holiday in the middle of each of the three periods into which the school year is divided http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/half-term?q=half-term

Comment: So how many days is he off?

Comment: Like the *summer holiday* between school years, the exact amount of time can vary depending on the school or schools in question. I recommend that you ask your boss.

Comment: So you say that half-term is a variable time period that is created by the school system?

Comment: It's part of the calendar for all schools in the UK and happens at about the same time in all of them. Jon Hanna gave a good explanation in his answer.